# When loading multiple TypedArrayContents arrays into a v8 array as elements (array of arrays), the last element overwrites all elements

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I am writing a C++ addon to node.js. I want to process and bundle a large amount of data into an array of arrays to pass from the C++ process back to js. I've learned that NAN provides a v8 helper class called TypedArrayContents, which lets me directly access a v8 Float32Array through a pointer.

```
v8::Local<Float32Array> tempHeatmap = v8::Float32Array::New(
        v8::ArrayBuffer::New(isolate, 4 * DIMENSIONS), 0, DIMENSIONS);

Nan::TypedArrayContents<float> dest(tempHeatmap);

for (int i = 0; i < heatmapCollection.size(); i++) {
        v8::Local<Array> sensorDataArray =
            Local<Array>::Cast(parentData->Get(i + 1));

        for (int a = 0; a < nodeCount; a++) {
            sensorDataVec[a] = sensorDataArray->Get(a)->NumberValue();
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < DIMENSIONS; j++) {
            float num = 0.0, denom = 0.0;
            for (int k = 0; k < nodeCount; k++) {
                if (heatmapGrid[j][k] == 0.0) {
                }
                else {

                    num += float(sensorDataVec[k]) / float(heatmapGrid[j][k]);

                    denom += 1 / float(heatmapGrid[j][k]);
                }
            }

            (*dest)[j] = num / denom;

        }
        returnHeatmapCollection->Set(i, tempHeatmap);

    }
```

returnHeatmapCollection is a v8 array that stores Float32Array's as elements. I can access it from js side no problem.

However, every element inside of returnHeatmapCollection defaults to the post-processing result of the **last** element. In other words, if I generate 10 tempHeatmap's, the 10th one is loaded into every element in returnHeatmapArray through ->Set().

Why would this occur? It makes infinitely less sense than if it defaulted to the **first** element. But the fact that the last element overwrites all previous ones would indicate that the every previous element is somehow modified every time I use ->Set. How can this be the case?

Answer (score 0):

You have a single `Float32Array` (declared outside of your  `for` loop) that you're setting to every index of `returnHeatmapCollection`. You need to make a new `Float32Array` for each index.